# When did "Twerking" and "Selfie" enter the dictionary?

Tags: meaning, slang, dictionaries

I read [in the news](http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/entertainment-arts-23861702) that *twerking* and *selfie* have been added to dictionary recently. Did it give any origin? Is there any information or details about them?

Comment: The article mentions Oxford Dictionaries Online: [twerk](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/twerk) | [selfie](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/selfie). The words don't appear in the online OED at the moment.

Comment: It is saddening that 'twerk' is an official word now.

Comment: I have the same opinion @mikhailcazi

Answer (score 7, accepted):

They were both added to Oxford Dictionaries Online last month.

The origin of *twerk* is given as ‘1990s: probably an alteration of *work*’ and of
*selfie*  as ‘early 21st century: from  *self* +  *-ie*’.